# Android Studioで作成したプログラムからLINEへメッセージを送付したい

Tags: java, android, line

最近、Android Studioで開発を始めたばかりなのですが、LINE Notifyで自身のライングループにテストで10文字程度のメッセージを送りたいのです。
LINE側のアクセストークン等は取得済であとはコードを記載するだけなのですが、どうコードを書けばいいのか解らず悩んでいます。

色々とググって調べてはみたのですが、参考のサイトはちらほらあるもののその通りにコード書いてもAndroid Studio側でエラーが出るので使えず、途方に暮れています。

申しわけないが何か参考になるサイト、ヒント、参考コードをご教授頂けると助かります。
宜しくお願い致します。

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    HttpSendJSON httpSendJSON = new HttpSendJSON();
    String result = httpSendJSON.callPost();
    System.out.println(result);
  }
}

class HttpSendJSON {
  private String ACCESS_TOKEN = "アクセストークン";
  private String UID = "ユーザID";
  private String MESSAGE = "送信したいメッセージ";

  public String callPost() {
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    try {
      URL url = new URL("https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/push");
      con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

      con.setDoOutput(true);
      con.setRequestMethod("POST");
      con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + ACCESS_TOKEN);
      con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

      String parameters = 
                "{" +
                String.format("\"to\": \"%s\",", UID) + 
                "    \"messages\": [{" +
                "        \"type\": \"text\"," +
                 String.format("\"text\": \"%s\"", MESSAGE) + 
                "    }]" +
                "}";
      System.out.println(parameters);

      OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
      out.write(parameters);
      out.flush();
      con.connect();

      final int status = con.getResponseCode();
      if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
          final InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
          String encoding = con.getContentEncoding();
          if (null == encoding) {
              encoding = "UTF-8";
          }
          final InputStreamReader inReader = new InputStreamReader(in, encoding);
          final BufferedReader bufReader = new BufferedReader(inReader);
          String line = null;

          while ((line = bufReader.readLine()) != null) {
              result.append(line);
          }
          bufReader.close();
          inReader.close();
          in.close();
      } else {
          System.out.println(status);
      }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
      e1.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if (con != null) {
        con.disconnect();
      }
    }
    return result.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: 何に詰まっているかわからないと、あてずっぽうのサイトしか紹介できないでしょう。まずはエラーを特定するほうが先かと思います。利用している環境(ソフトウェア、バージョン)、エラーが再現できる最低限のコード、エラーの詳細を記述頂けるとよりよい回答が出きると思います。

Comment: "LINE Notify" は「webサービスからの通知を LINE で受け取るサービス」のようですが、この API の選択で本当に合っていますか？

Comment: このサイトは見てらっしゃいますか？
http://ginkgo.hateblo.jp/entry/2017/11/18/131738
、

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。

Comment: 利用している開発環境はAndroid Studio ver 4.0.1です。
APIの選択は間違っていません。
今回実現したいことは”自作のAndroidアプリ→LINEへ簡単なメッセージを送る”です。
紹介頂いたサイトではアプリ起動してLINEも起動するようになっていますが、これでは毎回LINEで送信先を選択しなければいけないので不便です。
LINE notifyを使用すれば実現できると思うのですが。。。

Comment: 当方が書いたコードを追記しました。
これで実行までできるのですが、LINE側に何も通知が来ないのです。。。
【特段エラーは今のところ出ていません。】
追加情報として、manifest.xmlファイルには以下のインターネットアクセスへの許可としてコードを追記していますので動いてくれると思っていたのですが
動かないのです。。。
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

Comment: さらに追記します。
今回、アプリの画面上にボタンは実装しません。
一日1回、固定の時間になったらメッセージを送りたいだけなので
ボタンは不要です。
上記のコードはまず、LINE側にメッセージが届くかを先に確認したいため
TEST用で書きました。

Answer (score 0):

Androidでhttp通信を行う方法を整理してからOauthについての実装を行われたほうがいいと思います。

[AndroidでHTTP通信したいときの手段まとめ - Qiita](https://qiita.com/riversun/items/5f78d47a3d95f857d34f)

とりあえずでの疎通確認を行いたいのであればpostmanやその他http通信の記述しやすい言語で試験をした後に自作した通信系の実装を組み換えて開発されるのがよろしいのではないでしょうか？

Comment: auth系で踏み込んだ内容になりますと、Javaの標準のURLエンコードの方式とサービス提供側のエンコード方式が異なる場合があります。(私が検証した中ではgmailやtwitterは異なる方式でした。)回避策としてはライブラリを使用するか特定文字をエスケープする必要があったかと思われます。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。
他の言語ではC#トライしたのですが、うまくいっているのです。
なのでJavaで上記コードでいけると思ったのですがうまくいかず。。。。
自分でもどこが間違っているのかわからないのです。。。
Javaでは今回初めてだったので、まだ何か知らないやり方があるのかもしれません。
そこを指摘頂けるとたすかるのですが。。。。